# SQL Join returns duplicate entries

Tags: sql, join

Just going to start out saying that I am new to SQL and what I've written is based off of tutorials (Also I am using SQL Server 2012). The issue I am having is I am trying to take data from 4 different tables and put them into 1 table to be accessed by Access. However I keep getting duplicate results if a value is different from the rest.
The tables look like

Cell1

```
|LotNum|SerialNum|PassFail|
| Lot11|     1234|       1|
| Lot11|     2345|       1|
| Lot11|     3456|       1|
| Lot11|     4567|       1|
```

Cell2

```
|LotNum|SerialNum|PassFail|
| Lot11|     1234|       1|
| Lot11|     2345|       1|
| Lot11|     3456|       1|
| Lot11|     4567|       1|
```

Cell3

```
|LotNum|SerialNum|PassFail|
| Lot11|     1234|       1|
| Lot11|     2345|       1|
| Lot11|     3456|       1|
| Lot11|     4567|       1|
```

Cell4

```
|LotNum|SerialNum|PassFail|
| Lot11|     1234|       1|
| Lot11|     2345|       1|
| Lot11|     3456|       1|
| Lot11|     4567|       0|
```

My code is

```
Alter Procedure [dbo].[spSingleData](
@LotNum varchar(50)
)
AS
Truncate Table dbo.SingleSheet
Begin
Insert INTO dbo.SingleSheet (SerialNum, Cell1PF, Cell2Pf, Cell3PF, Cell4PF)
Select Distinct Cell1.SerialNum, Cell1.PF, Cell2.PF, Cell3.PF, Cell4.PF
From dbo.Cell1
Left Join Cell2 On Cell1.LotNum=Cell2.LotNum
Left Join Cell3 On Cell1.LotNum=Cell3.LotNum
Left Join Cell4 On Cell1.LotNum=Cell4.LotNum
Where Cell1.LotNum = @LotNum
Order by SerialNum
End
```

PassFail can be 0, 1, or NULL, however, like in the example above, if one of the PassFails is different from the rest, the resulting table returns

```
|1234|   1|   1|   1|    0|
|1234|   1|   1|   1|    1|
|2345|   1|   1|   1|    0|
|2345|   1|   1|   1|    1|
|3456|   1|   1|   1|    0|
|3456|   1|   1|   1|    1|
|4567|   1|   1|   1|    0|
|4567|   1|   1|   1|    1|
```

Am I just using the wrong Join or should I be using something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve:

If so then you are missing a `JOIN` predicate on `SerialNum` and you do not need the `DISTINCT`

Sample Data:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Cell1') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Cell1
CREATE TABLE #Cell1 (LotNum varchar(10),SerialNum int,PassFail bit)
INSERT INTO #Cell1
VALUES
('Lot11',1234,1),
('Lot11',2345,1),
('Lot11',3456,1),
('Lot11',4567,1)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Cell2') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Cell2
CREATE TABLE #Cell2 (LotNum varchar(10),SerialNum int,PassFail bit)
INSERT INTO #Cell2
VALUES
('Lot11',1234,1),
('Lot11',2345,1),
('Lot11',3456,1),
('Lot11',4567,1)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Cell3') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Cell3
CREATE TABLE #Cell3 (LotNum varchar(10),SerialNum int,PassFail bit)
INSERT INTO #Cell3
VALUES
('Lot11',1234,1),
('Lot11',2345,1),
('Lot11',3456,1),
('Lot11',4567,1)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Cell4') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Cell4
CREATE TABLE #Cell4 (LotNum varchar(10),SerialNum int,PassFail bit)
INSERT INTO #Cell4
VALUES
('Lot11',1234,1),
('Lot11',2345,1),
('Lot11',3456,1),
('Lot11',4567,0)
```

Query:

```
SELECT #Cell1.SerialNum,
       #Cell1.PassFail,
       #Cell2.PassFail,
       #Cell3.PassFail,
       #Cell4.PassFail
FROM #Cell1
     LEFT JOIN #Cell2 ON #Cell1.LotNum = #Cell2.LotNum AND #Cell1.SerialNum = #Cell2.SerialNum
     LEFT JOIN #Cell3 ON #Cell1.LotNum = #Cell3.LotNum AND #Cell1.SerialNum = #Cell3.SerialNum
     LEFT JOIN #Cell4 ON #Cell1.LotNum = #Cell4.LotNum AND #Cell1.SerialNum = #Cell4.SerialNum
ORDER BY SerialNum;
```

Results:

[image]